# Support for sharing stories on Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Is there a way to write this code block cleaner and more readable?

```
 var shareNavigate = function () {
     scope.sharingActions.shareOnFacebook().done(function () {
             app.router.navigateToStories();
         });
 },
     sharePublishNavigate = function () {
         scope.sharingActions.shareOnFacebook().done(function () {
                 scope.model.publish().done(function () {
                         app.router.navigateToStories();
                     });
             });
     },
     loginSharePublishNavigate = function () {
         facebookActions.login().done(function () {
                 sharePublishNavigate();
             });
     };
 if (!noViews && hasEditPermissions) {
     shareNavigate();
 } else if (noViews) {
     if (hasEditPermissions) {
         sharePublishNavigate();
     } else if (!isLoggeedIn) {
         loginSharePublishNavigate();
     } else {
         shareNavigate();
     }
 }
```

First I define functions and then in each case I call the relevant function. I am using jQuery deferreds and since I need operation to done, I have many nested methods. Is there any way to beautify this code?

Comment: First thing: use correct indentation!

Comment: Any reason for sharing something, and _then_ publishing it? Seems exactly backwards to me.

Comment: By the way, you can probably use [`.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) to your advantage, provided you're using jQuery 1.8+: `scope.sharingActions.shareOnFacebook().then(scope.model.publish).then(app.router.navigateToStories);`

Comment: Why do you declare those functions locally instead of in an object of their own?

Comment: Agree @Flambino, and I would put each `.then` on a new line, I know that isn't possible in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I like comma separated variable definitions, but they ten to get messy when there are assignments or when they become multi-line. A suggestion I found on the net is to only use comma separated declarations *if they are not assignments*. If they are assignments, `var` them individually instead. looks cleaner and prevents stray `,`.

```
//declarations only
var foo, bar, baz;

//assignments:
var foo = 1;
var bar = 2;
var baz = 3;
```

When declaring functions, I'd stick to using "function declarations" rather than the "function expressions" since:

- They contain lesser characters
- They don't look like variables at first sight
- Hoisting advantage (the compiler pulls them up the scope so they look like they are declared on top, regardless of where you place them in the code)
- Avoids the trailing `;` (you'll know when you use linters)
- They are named which avoids issues with debuggers (better safe then sorry).

The notational difference is the following

```
//expression - NOT THIS
var foo = function(){/*...*/};

//declaration - THIS!
function foo(){/*...*/}
```

As for your nesting functions, they look fine but I suggest you indent properly.

There *is* a minor overhead in object property access, and you can cache them for shorter access. However, it's a trade-off between readability at times.

You can also assign the function name as callback directly rather than create a function that only calls another function.

```
var shareOnFacebook = scope.sharingActions.shareOnFacebook;


function loginSharePublishNavigate() {
  facebookActions.login().done(sharePublishNavigate);
}

function shareNavigate() {
  shareOnFacebook().done(app.router.navigateToStories);
}

function sharePublishNavigate() {
  shareOnFacebook().done(function () {
    scope.model.publish().done(app.router.navigateToStories);
  });
}
```

For boolean-containing variables, I suggest to be uniform in the name. I usually name them in the `true` state and prefixed with `is` or `has`. So instead of using `noViews`, I suggest you use `hasViews`. That way, the conditions will not be garbled in meaning:

```
//instead of
if(!noViews && hasEditPermissions){/*...*/}

//use this
if(hasViews && hasEditPermissions){/*...*/}
```

As for the logic, I can't quite figure it out. Here are the possible combinations of the 3 variables used.

```
view edit login
0    0    0     = loginSharePublishNavigate
0    0    1     = shareNavigate
0    1    0     = sharePublishNavigate
0    1    1     = sharePublishNavigate
1    0    0     = ?
1    0    1     = ?
1    1    0     = shareNavigate
1    1    1     = shareNavigate
```

Let's say we factor out `loggedIn` as our first check and should do `loginSharePublishNavigate` when not logged in.

```
view edit login
/*
0    0    0     = loginSharePublishNavigate
0    1    0     = loginSharePublishNavigate
1    1    0     = loginSharePublishNavigate
1    0    0     = loginSharePublishNavigate
*/
1    0    1     = ? <- what handles this???
0    1    1     = sharePublishNavigate
0    0    1     = shareNavigate
1    1    1     = shareNavigate
```

Still, can't figure it out. If I do some K-map on this, I might get the right combinations, but end up with a more complex condition. Anyways, a generic suggestion is you do filtering rather than nesting:

```
if(!loggedIn){
  //now in here, it's executing `!loggedIn`
  //not logged in
}
//ok, so we are logged in, what next?
else if(!hasPermissions){
  //now in here, it's like executing `loggedIn && !hasPermissions`
  //no permissions
}
//ok, we are now logged in and have permissions, what next?
else if(!anotherCheck){
  //now in here, it's like executing `loggedIn && hasPermissions && !anotherCheck`
} 
//...and so on...
else {
  //now in here, it's like executing `loggedIn && hasPermissions && anotherCheck`
  //ok, every check is true by this block
}
```

We avoided nesting. But this only works in linear conditions. If there are more complex conditions, this won't work. Also, it passes through more checks when all conditions are `true` which means more overhead. But it's a trade-off for readable code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer to rewrite this

```
 if (!noViews && hasEditPermissions) {
     shareNavigate();
 } else if (noViews) {
     if (hasEditPermissions) {
         sharePublishNavigate();
     } else if (!isLoggeedIn) {
         loginSharePublishNavigate();
     } else {
         shareNavigate();
     }
 }
```

To this:

```
 if (hasEditPermissions) {
     if (noViews) {
         sharePublishNavigate();
     } else {
         shareNavigate();
     }
 } else {
     if(loggeedIn) {
         shareNavigate();
     } else {
         loginSharePublishNavigate();
     }
 }
```

The `!noViews` is redundant and it is usually confusing if you start an if-else expression with a negation. Besides that, try avoiding `else if` in favor of nested expressions. You should also try to make the boolean expressions functionally independent - if you have checked `noViews` somewhere, don't check it again.

I am not sure if the truth table for the two blocks are identical. I'll leave that up to you to verify.

Answer (score 1):

You would possibly be better off with `login`, `share`, `publish` and `navigate` as promise-returning worker functions:

```
var login = function() { return isLoggedIn ? null : facebookActions.login(); }
var share = function() { return scope.sharingActions.shareOnFacebook(); };
var publish = function() { return scope.model.publish() };
var navigate = function() { return app.router.navigateToStories() };
```

Now you can sequence these workers with `.then()` as follows (or similar) :

```
var rootPromise = $.Deferred().resolve().promise();

if (noViews) {
    if(hasEditPermissions || !isLoggedIn) {
        rootPromise.then(login).then(share).then(publish).then(navigate);
    }
    else {
        rootPromise.then(share).then(navigate);
    }
}
else if(hasEditPermissions) {
    rootPromise.then(share).then(navigate);
}
```

Notes:

- `rootPromise` isn't strictly necessary but keeps rest of the code tidier, particularly `login()`.
- `login()` returns `null` if already logged in, allowing the calling logic to be slightly simpler.
- The whole thing may simplify further depending in part on the relationship between `hasEditPermissions` and `isLoggedIn` (See other answers for suggestions).

Comment: Why did you made:  rootPromise.then(login).then(share).then(publish).then(navigate);
instead of:  login().then(share).then(publish).then(navigate);

Comment: I was wondering if you might ask. As I said, `rootPromise` isn't strictly necessary and yes, `login()...`. is the other way to proceed but in that case `login()` would need to return a promise under both conditions - `isLoggedIn` and `!isLoggedIn` - otherwise `login().then()` would throw an error. Using a ready-resolved "rootPromise"  or "starterPromose" is quite a common technique when building `.then()` chains.